# What seed value should I use for erand48() in C?

Tags: c, random, concurrency

I am new to C programming, and i've read that erand48() is a good option for thread-safe random number generation. However the function takes a seed value of: unsigned short int array[3]

Any recommendations as to what this seed value should be initialized to?

Comment: Why not the same as `srand`: `time`? Since you have a couple more bits to fill, perhaps throw in the `pid` as well.

Comment: @Jongware because `time` ain't updated anywhere close to enough for there to be a difference across threads (1s for `libc:time`, <1ms for `pthread:create`).

Comment: @haneef: thanks! I entirely forgot about the threading, and indeed it's likely (if not downright *usually*) multiple threads will be created in the exact same millisecond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright. So first, let me make it clear that the PRNG in `libc` is deterministic (that's why it wants a seed), uses an [LCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) - meaning it's easy to predict all of the values once you have a few, and is therefore insecure.

Now then. `erand48()` returns a random floating point value of `double` size from a uniform distribution of pseudorandom real numbers. It doesn't take a seed value per se, but rather requires you to provide a state buffer. Here's the full declaration:

```
double erand48(unsigned short xsubi[3]);
```

The state buffer, amusingly enough, must be seeded by a random value in order for the generator to work. My first thought was to read from `/dev/urandom`.

We can do that with something like this (using unbuffered reads to prevent wastage from such small reads):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *thread_f (void *i) {
    // setup unbuffered urandom
    urandom = fopen ("/dev/urandom", "r");
    setvbuf (urandom, NULL, _IONBF, 0);  // turn off buffering

    // setup state buffer
    unsigned short randstate[3];
    // fgetc() returns a `char`, we need to fill a `short`
    randstate[0] = (fgetc (urandom) << 8) | fgetc (urandom);
    randstate[1] = (fgetc (urandom) << 8) | fgetc (urandom);
    randstate[2] = (fgetc (urandom) << 8) | fgetc (urandom);


    // cleanup urandom
    fclose (urandom);

    // you can now use erand48 (randstate);

    ...     // do whatever work you need to do

    return result;
}
```

This is thread safe, and even ensures a relatively safe seed value for all of the threads.

Of course, if speed isn't too much of an issue (ie: you can live with a small loss of speed) and you can live with integers, then doing unbuffered reads directly from `/dev/urandom` is a perfect solution. Even better, /dev/urandom provides secure, unpredictable pseudorandom integers (well, technically, a byte stream, but they will always work as integers as long as you match the size) that are also usually uniformly distributed.

Plus, `/dev/urandom` periodically has entropy injected into it and refreshed, ensuring that you have a decent supply of fairly random numbers.

Comment: The IO functions ARE thread safe (that's why you have getc_unlocked & friends); (nitpick-on) fgetc returns a single byte, you need two, and the LCG link points to LFSR (nitpick-off)

Comment: @loreb I don't know why I thought they weren't. Anyways, fixed the LCG and the `fgetc()`. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

Just my 2 cents...

We used the same function-family in one of our projects sometime ago. The product had to work on Windows/Unix, so we did not use **/dev/random**.

Instead, we concatenated the **host_ip_addr + time() + process_id + thread_id** as a string and generated a hash from this string. And then, we spread XOR'ed the trailing bytes onto the 6 leading bytes. We used that final data as our seed...

Answer (score 0):

The rand48 family is a 48 bit LCG, meaning something like

```
double erand48(uint48_t *state) {
    *state = *state * A + C;             /* A and C are suitable values */
    return *state / 281474976710656.0;   /* that's 2^48 */
}
```

... except that I've never seen a computer with an uint48_t, so what you pass around is an array with 48 bits of state (3x16 assuming that a short has 16 bits).
You can seed it with anything - just get 48 random bits and shove them into array[3], from /dev/urandom, from time/pid/whatever.

A few gotchas:
- lcong48() - forget it even exists
- "how do I make sure that two seeds are not ridiculously close to each other?" - don't, it would take less time to just use another rng.